# Want the list of all files given the folder name?

Tags: ruby

I want the list of all files given the folder name, i.e. it should traverse deep inside given the folder name ?
If I give any path like 'employee/app',it should list all files deep inside 'employee/app' folders

Answer (score 6):

What about a nice typeglob:

```
p Dir['**/*']
```

Comment: `Dir[**/*]` can cause scalability problems if it's descending into a directory hierarchy containing a lot of files and/or folders. The names will be loaded into memory at once. Ruby's [`Find`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/find/1.9.2/frames) should be more predictable.

Comment: Just curious, Is there something like Dir.glob("specific dir path", "**/*")? that avoids changing the current directory as in `Dir.chdir("c:/temp"){|path| puts path; puts Dir["**/*"]}`

Comment: @the Tin Man - learned something new with Find. So Find does the probing bit - the matching bit has to be written by hand ? e.g. `Find.find("w:/code"){|path| puts path if path =~ /Unity/}`